# Store Google Maps markers in SharedPreferences

Tags: android, google-maps, android-activity, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to store my GMaps markers, so when I press back button, and back another time to my maps activity, show my markers on screen.

I've checked out this post [Save state when back button is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12171320/save-the-state-when-back-buton-is-pressed) and I got some results, but I'm still far way from my initial objective.

Now I can see my first marker and my last one.

Here goes my code:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.
    private List<Marker> markerList;

    public MapsActivity(){
        if(markerList == null){
            markerList = new ArrayList<Marker>();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        setUpMapIfNeeded();

        LoadPreferences();
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle data = intent.getExtras();
        String label = data.getString("sum");
        int newLatitude = data.getInt("firstNumber");
        int newLongitude = data.getInt("secondNumber");

        MarkerOptions mo = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(newLatitude, newLongitude)).title(label);
        markerList.add(mMap.addMarker(mo));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        super.onBackPressed();
        SavePreferences();
    }

    private void SavePreferences(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        editor.putInt("listSize", markerList.size());

        for(int i = 0; i <markerList.size(); i++){
            editor.putFloat("lat"+i, (float) markerList.get(0).getPosition().latitude);
            editor.putFloat("long"+i, (float) markerList.get(0).getPosition().longitude);
            editor.putString("title"+i, markerList.get(0).getTitle());
        }

        editor.commit(); 
    }

    private void LoadPreferences(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);

        int size = sharedPreferences.getInt("listSize", 0);
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            double lat = (double) sharedPreferences.getFloat("lat"+i,0);
            double longit = (double) sharedPreferences.getFloat("long"+i,0);
            String title = sharedPreferences.getString("title"+i,"NULL");

            markerList.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, longit)).title(title)));
        }
    }
}
```

My question is how can I store my markers that when I back to maps activity show them? (Using this or another approach)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**problem:**

```
markerList.get(0)
```

You are only saving the first index of your array of markers

**solution:**

feed the index from the foorloop

```
markerList.get(i)
```

Comment: I'm really ashamed! This was just my inattention! Sorry guys!

Comment: @guisantogui happens sometimes to me :))

Answer (score 1):

Marker marker;
 Now this marker object cannot be stored directly into sharedpreferences. i also faced the same issue and after a lot research i got to this conclusion that sharedpreferences can only stores data of single primitive type  like int,long,double,string etc or collection of these primitive data type  like pojo(by using libraries like Gson).

so if you want to store your marker you can simply get its location in form of

double latitute =marker.getposition.latitude;
double longitute=marker.getposition().longitude;

and then store these doubles inside shared preferences. but if you want answer for direct marker object storage into shared preferences then i am sure you will not find any on stackoverflows, i did all the research related to this.