# How the spinner items not be kept selected as it is while rerunning the app

Tags: android, spinner

Hello I want to Know that how can i keep the spinner items selected throughout the activity so that if i come back form other activity to the activity that is consisting of spinner its still remain selected as it is.

The above statement that i have used that has been solved after this there is an another issue that whenever i restart my app its the selected portion remains as it is i want to know what i can do so that the spinner does not show what i have selected before

I have a code of spinner which i want to keep it selected throughout all the activities   ,

```
daySelection = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.daypreferance);
        //String[] dayName = new String[]{
          //      "sunday", "monday", "tuesday" 
        //};

        MyClass[] dayName ={

                new MyClass("sunday", ""),
                new MyClass("monday", "2"),
                new MyClass("tuesday", "3")



        };
        ArrayAdapter<MyClass> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<MyClass>(this , R.layout.spinner_items ,R.id.spinneritem,dayName);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_items);
        hotelSelection.setAdapter(adapter);

        daySelection.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                preferDay=  parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();


            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        daySelection = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.daypreferance);


        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        prefs.edit().putInt("spinner_indx", daySelection.getSelectedItemPosition()).apply();

    }
 public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        daySelection = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.daypreferance);


        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        int spinnerIndx = prefs.getInt("spinner_indx", 0);


        daySelection.setSelection(spinnerIndx);

    }
```

I need to add the code that  whenever I restart my app its the selected portion remains as it is I want to know what I can do so that the spinner does not show what I have selected before

Comment: You can take one static variable in activity and set it with selected position and on same activity in onResume method set spinner selection by that variable

Comment: @Vickyexpert why static?

Comment: @Moulick don't finish the current activity having spinner just go to next activity when u have done with that just finish the activity, automatically previous activity will be resumed and your selection will not lost.

Comment: but how to do that  usually after filling the data i will go to next activity to show its summary and if i think i need to go back i will come back to this activity(view) and it should show whatever i selected before

Answer (score 0):

try dis and let me know if any error....

```
daySelection = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.daypreferance);
            //String[] dayName = new String[]{
              //      "sunday", "monday", "tuesday" 
            //};

            MyClass[] dayName ={

                    new MyClass("sunday", ""),
                    new MyClass("monday", "2"),
                    new MyClass("tuesday", "3")



            };
            ArrayAdapter<MyClass> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<MyClass>(this , R.layout.spinner_items ,R.id.spinneritem,dayName);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_items);
            hotelSelection.setAdapter(adapter);

            daySelection.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    //check if preferDay has some valur rhen set on spinner
                     if(preferDay!=null)
    {
                     daySelection.setSelection(Integer.parseInt(preferDay));
    }


                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: preferDay doesnt have any value i have used it to convert it to string so that i can put it on text view on other activity as summery

Comment: den follow the answer of 

@Pierfrancesco

Answer (score 0):

you can save state of activity and then set those values after came back

check [this stack over flow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/151940/3472667)  and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12171498/3472667)

Answer (score 0):

Save the state of the spinner in the onPause() method.

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
   super.onPause();

   Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.daypreferance);

   SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   prefs.edit().putInt("spinner_indx", spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()).apply();
}
```

Restore the state of the spinner in the onResume() method.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
   super.onResume();

   Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.daypreferance);

   SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   int spinnerIndx = prefs.getInt("spinner_indx", 0);
   spinner.setSelection(spinnerIndx);
}
```

Comment: just copy-paste my code and replace "spinner" with your actual spinner :)

Comment: no that i understand but these 2 methods onPause and onResume how can i place it inside that code because i have 3 more spinner content also

Comment: Add this methods (onPause and onResume) to your Activity.
You can add how many spinners you want, with the same principle.

Comment: its showing error on set selection as "cannot resolve setSelection(int)"

Comment: still the same issue

Comment: hey hey just one issue it worked on the first one but after rerunning the app the selected item didnt changed and on applying on other spinners it wasnt working

Comment: I answered your question, now I don't understand what you're talking about. Just add another int preference for each Spinner.

Comment: i was saying on re running the app again if i have selected monday its always showing monday other then that it should show sunday

Comment: Just reset the preference in the onStop method. And study some good theory ;) here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

and here:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Comment: i think i need onStop code for this how i should onStop method so that when ever i am rerunning the app the the spinner items remain unselected